# Find records in join table that only have a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table

```
recipe_food_xref
recipe_id int
food_id int
```

Need to find the one record in recipe_food_xref where the recipe has only one food and that food is a specific food.

It works perfectly joining to itself:

```
SELECT x1.recipe_id FROM recipe_food_xref x1
INNER JOIN recipe_food_xref x2 ON x2.recipe_id = x1.recipe_id
WHERE x1.food_id = 1
GROUP BY x1.recipe_id
HAVING COUNT(x2.recipe_id) = 1
```

That seems a bit ugly and I'd like to know if there's a better way.

Here's a SqlFiddle with some sample data.  Basically I want to find recipe_id:1 since it has food_id:1 and does not have more than one food_id

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d474/1

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT recipe_id 
FROM recipe_food_xref
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING sum(case when food_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
and sum(case when food_id <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d474/5)

Comment: Interesting take on the problem  I'm curious if the case statements are better or worse than the join against self.  Guess I'll have to compare the execution plans

Answer (score 1):

This was my first go:

```
SELECT recipe_id
FROM recipe_food_xref
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING COUNT(food_id) = 1 AND SUM(food_id) = 1;
```

Note that the general format is `HAVING COUNT(FOOD_ID) = 1 AND SUM(FOOD_ID) = <food id>`. It works because, if there is only one food_id, then the sum is equal to the id.

Seems similar to Juergen's answer but simpler. Did I miss something?

I also tried the following, which has to scan the table extra times but as I'd never used the `ALL` keyword before so I thought it was interesting.

```
SELECT recipe_id
FROM recipe_food_xref AS r
WHERE 1 = ALL (SELECT food_id FROM recipe_food_xref WHERE r.recipe_id=recipe_id);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d474/26

Comment: Yep, this seems to work as well.  And has roughly the same execution plan as juergen's

Comment: True, simpler text in the query doesn't necessarily mean simpler/better/different execution path.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from recipe_food_xref x
where not exists (
                   select i.food_id
                   from recipe_food_xref i
                   where i.recipe_id = x.recipe_id and
                         i.food_id <> x.food_id
                 ) 
-- if this is omitted you get all recipes having just one food:
      and x.food_id = 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure that a sub select is any better than the self join.  Still has to scan the same table twice.

Comment: @dstarh I can imagine the `group by` is heavy. But perhaps you can find out if you have a look at the query execution plans...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my interpretation of the problem:

> Find all recipes with a single ingredient. Of these recipes, find the one whose single ingredient is X

```
SELECT recipe_id
     , Max(food_id) As food_id
     , Count(*) As number_of_ingredients
FROM   recipe_food_xref
GROUP
    BY recipe_id
HAVING Count(*) = 1
AND    Max(food_id) = 1
```